# QPainter equivalent in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, qt, qt4, objective-c++

I'm trying to translate a Qt project in Objective-C

It is a blockbraker.
I need to find the equivalent for QPainter, un Qt object that call the Windows fonction to draw something on the screen.

So I need anything that allows me to draw lines, ellipse and, most important of all, png images.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to have a look at the [Cocoa Drawing Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html), which explains how to draw things in Cocoa. Specifically, the `NSBezierPath` lets you draw shapes, and `NSImage` lets you work with PNGs. But there are other classes you need to know about in order to change colors, etc.